# How to pass a 'symbol_name' into an action?

Tags: action, asset, symbol-name

Does anyone know how to pass an assets `symbol_name` in as an argument to an action?  I have been trying the following:

.abi

```
"types": [{
"new_type_name": "symbol_name",
"type": "uint64"
}]
```

and .cpp

```
void contract::getsymbol(symbol_name sym) {
    print("Symbol is ", name{sym});
}
```

However when I try to pass in a symbol like `TEST` a get the following error:

Couldn't parse uint64_t

Answer (score 1):

`void contract::getsymbol(string sym) {
    symbol_type symb = string_to_symbol(4,sym.c_str());
    print("Symbol is ", sym);
    print(symb.name());
}`

Comment: As I am not able to see your code but I think you  would probabily imported the symbol.hpp  .Did your code work ?